# Getting display name of the site on which question is located

Tags: feature-request, api-v2, questions, sites

When using the `/questions` method to retrieve a particular question, I'd like to also get the display name of the site on which the question is located (e.g., *User Experience*). At present, the API does not return a *site* object with this information.

Brock Adams gave an explanation of various ways one can get around this limitation. They work, but I hope that the feature merits consideration for inclusion in a later version of the API.

---

*Original form of the question, to which the answer refers*

When using the `/questions` method to get a particular question, is there a way to also get the display name of the site on which the question is located? The method appears to be able to return *site* type, but there is no *site* field nested under *question*. Am I missing something?

(Incidentally: for *migrated* questions, one can get the name and other information for the site from which the question *came*.)

I understand that I can get the site's display name using `/sites`, but that means making another call just for this small piece of information.

Answer (score 2):

You already know the site, it has to be built in to every `/questions` query.  But, if you are querying separate sites with concurrent AJAX queries, merely encapsulate the site name in your AJAX callback.  [See this Stack Overflow question for an example of doing that in javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1194104/331508)

Alternatively, you can parse [the `link` property of the question response](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) to determine the site.

EG: The question response returns a `link` for each question like this:

```
"link": "http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176660/how-to-configure-applied-en"
```

So, just extract the domain:

```js
var qLink   = "http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176660/how-to-configure-applied-energistics-to-increase-item-count-to-an-exact-value-wh";
var qDomain = qLink.match (/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)/i)[1];
// Yields: "gaming.stackexchange.com"
```

[You can then use the domain for the `site` for subsequent calls](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs#tabs):

> **Per-Site Methods**
>   Each of these methods operates on a single site at a time, identified by the `site` parameter. **This parameter can be the full domain name** (ie. "stackoverflow.com"), or a short form identified by `api_site_parameter` on the site object.

For example, these calls all yield the same results:

- [api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=gaming](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=gaming&pagesize=1)
- [api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=gaming.stackexchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=gaming.stackexchange&pagesize=1)
- [api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=gaming.stackexchange.com](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=gaming.stackexchange.com&pagesize=1)
- [api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=arqade.com](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=arqade.com&pagesize=1)
- [api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=thearqade.com](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=thearqade.com&pagesize=1)

(The last 2 domains are aliases for the Gaming site.)

---

If you really want the English name, EG "Arqade", then **look up the domain**, as determined above, **in a table that your app cached** after calling `/sites` *once* per app session or once per day.

Comment: You can get it for migrated sites because they are returned in a `site` object.  The API designers saw no need to return a `site` object for the question itself. ... As for client-side JS.  Either just run `/sites` once per page load or cache the results in localStorage.  It's not hard and works well, on average.